# Azure AD 2.0 application - can't access scope from angular client

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to develop Angular 4 application and ASP.NET Core 2.0 backend. I have angular application (generated using Angular-cli) and .net core web api (generated using vs 2017 template). 
On angular side I'm using [angular-oauth2-oidc](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc). I registered my application using AzureAD [app registration portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com) (app s registered as v2.0) in the app configuration there is two platforms Web and Web API. 
In Web api platform there is defined scope named "api:///access_as_user" and my application is given access to this scope.
[image: App registration]

On angular side that's it. On .NET side there is .AddJwtBearer() method that has configured authority, audience (clientId).

```
services.AddAuthentication(auth =>
        {
            auth.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            auth.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>/v2.0";                
            cfg.Audience = "<clientId>";
            //cfg.Configuration = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfiguration();
            cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidIssuer = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>/v2.0"
            };              
        });
```

The problem occurs when I tried to access my web api from client application. If I don't ask for my scope ("api:///access_as_user") in angular, web api return 401 unauthorized. I I ask for it I get

```
"AADSTS65005:The application 'Angular-test' asked for scope 'access_as_user' that doesn't exist on the resource. Contact the app vendor.
Trace+ID: c55338dd-35c8-429b-bfe1-5c48ac030d00
Correlation+ID: a0b4bc2d-7f15-4ca4-9cd5-4fe61999e4d9 
Timestamp:+2017-10-24+10:35:56Z""
```

Anyone has the same/simular issue?

Git repositories:

[Client](https://github.com/alan994/Angular-playground/tree/oidc) --> branch **oidc**

[Servier](https://github.com/alan994/Angular-playground-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to call the web api by not using the customize scope. Here are the steps for your reference:

1.Acquire the token using the implicit flow like below:

```
GET: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=id_token&client_id=1e6af2ed-686c-4914-96ed-0cd7b1673cbb&scope=openid&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&nonce=123
```

2.1 **multi-tenant**:

Call the .net core web API using the id_token above which protect the Azure AD V2.0 app like code below:

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
{
        Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/",
        Audience = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ClientId"],
        Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnAuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed
        },
        TokenValidationParameters=new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer =false,          
        } 
    });        
});
```

2.1 **limit the tenants as you wanted**:

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
{
    Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/",
    Audience = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ClientId"],
    Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnAuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed
    },
    TokenValidationParameters=new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer =true,
        ValidIssuers=new string[] { "list the allowed issues here","https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-0e9b-42f8-8b22-3c4a2f1d8800/v2.0"}
    } 
});
```

You can refer the code sample below about protecting the web api using Azure AD V2.0 app. The code sample is for Azure AD B2C, we can modify its **authority** to make it working for Azure AD V2.0 app. And please feel free to let me know if you still have the problem.

[active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapi](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapi)

Comment: In this sample only difference is Authority /common/ I get /tenantId/. As far as I know common is for multitenant apps. But I don't see any button for choosing multitenant apps on new portal (in azure there is button).

I added links to demo projects, can you please take a look and maybe give me some hint. If you try to run it (client branch oidc) you will see that i get the token (console and session storage) in app.component.ts in line 23 I ser scope only for graph api now. But server reject token with 401. Action that triggers request with token is Books --> Add.

Comment: @AlanJagar The app which using Azure AD V2.0 endpoint supports the multi-tenant by default. Is the apps only for your organization? If yes, you can limit the issues using the `ValidIssuers`. I have update the code for these two scenarios. Please let me know if you have problem.

Comment: I need multitenant. I tried your example but still get an 401. 
Client app redirect me to this url
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=id_token%20token&client_id=2183b5f0-4529-4e72-a6b4-4e06fe2c4a73&state=cF3oAQwuiNM6pGb72Z6urmTd3F1Wm7bKyqDuYSAn&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fhome&scope=openid&nonce=cF3oAQwuiNM6pGb72Z6urmTd3F1Wm7bKyqDuYSAn`

And I get the token, but server is still give me 401.

Comment: If you don't want to limit the tenants, you can just disable the issue verifying.  For the 401 error, is there any detailed error message?

Comment: Server code:
`.AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
   {
    cfg.Audience = "2183b5f0-4529-4e72-a6b4-4e06fe2c4a73";
    cfg.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0";
    
    //cfg.Configuration = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfiguration();
    cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
     ValidateIssuer =false
    };    
   });`

Comment: The token you are acquiring is the access token for Microsoft Graph. You should send the **id_token** instead of the **access_token**.

Comment: Normally, the access token is specific for the target resource via the `aud` claim. However Azure AD V2.0 seems have problem to acquire the access_token for the customize web API. So as a workaround, you can send the id_token to your web API. Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: It's working :). Thanks so much. So as far as I understood when I call graph api I need to send access token and when I call my web api I need to send Id_token.